# CAKEPHP find using a ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I want to do a `$this->find` using a id of an ajax request.

I has 2 selects and I want to, if I choice one option its return a select related with this id.

This is my function:

```
if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->layout = false;
        $id = $this->request->data['select'];
        $this->set('filial',$this->Branch->find('list', array('conditions' => array('company_id' => $id ))));
    }
```

And this is my ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#AttorneyEmpresa").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                data: { select: $('#AttorneyEmpresa').val()},
                sucess: function(data) {
                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

I want to execute the action, get the data of find and fill the select.
How I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in the `success` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#AttorneyEmpresa").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                data: { select: $('#AttorneyEmpresa').val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

Comment: Nothing is returning.
I tested in "complete", put alert(data) and the alert is "Object Object"

Answer (score 0):

try to change with `selected_value` instead of `select`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#AttorneyEmpresa").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                data: { selected_value: $('#AttorneyEmpresa').val()},
                sucess: function(data) {
                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

and also check in controller is valid id is posted on ajax request ?

and verify data in controller after find query. or if you dont have layout then you can also use `json` data to return in response to ajax function.

let me know if i can help you more.